# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - JQuery + PHP Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I am having a lot of trouble getting this code to work, I keep getting Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded errors in chrome.

I am trying to pass data over to a mail form to send myself an email with the form data.

I've tried changing things up and not using .val(). Any help would be appreciated. I've tried calling it within my javascript, and as an onclick for the submit button. Both throw the same error.

```
function SubmitFormData() {
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var phone = $("#phone").val();
var name = $("#website").val();

var goals = $("#goals").val();
var reach = $("#reach").val();
var leadorsale = $("#leadorsale").val();
var monthlyppc = $("#monthlyppc").val();

$.post("mailform.php", { name: name, email: email, phone: phone,         
website: website, goals: goals, reach: reach, leadorsale: 
leadorsale,     monthlyppc: monthlyppc});
}
```

I would like the code to execute and send data to my php file.

Comment: This code by itself wouldnt cause that error. That error tends to occur from using some recursive function call. Provide a [mcve]. For instance how does SubmitFormData get called, what code/line does the error point to, etc

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw this answer on similar queries on here. The thing is I have no other code executing, I am also not using any recursion.

Comment: Then you need to provide a more complete sample of code. And just because you arent explicitly calling a function recursively doesnt mean it isnt happening.

Comment: I've narrowed the issue down to "var name = $("#name").var();". If i pass defined strings into the function everything works. Is there any other solution to getting value="" from the input fields in the html? Thanks for your help.

Comment: "var name = $("#name").varl();" not  "var name = $("#name").var();".

Comment: solved by using vanilla JS to get the value of the input id: document.getElementById('name').value; not sure why jquery was throwing the error.